# How do I extract the label with the highest confidence value and print it out in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase-mlkit, vision, google-mlkit

```
private func showResults(_ results: [(label: String, confidence: 
Float)]?) {
    var resultsText = Constants.failedToDetectObjectsMessage
    if let results = results {
      resultsText = results.reduce("") { (resultString, result) -> 
String in
        let (label, confidence) = result
        return resultString + "\(label): \(String(describing: 
confidence))\n"
      }
    }
    resultsAlertController.message = resultsText
    resultsAlertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.annotationOverlayView.frame
    resultsAlertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.annotationOverlayView
    present(resultsAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    print(resultsText)
}
```

This is the sample code that I have tried. How do i extract the label with the highest confidence value and print it out?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to StackOverflow. If you could add the actual code instead of a screenshot, along with what you have already tried, it would help a lot to receive a meaningful answer.

Comment: @matt I think that's what OP is asking for: how to only show the label with the highest confidence level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to know which label has the highest confidence level is to call `max(by:)` on the `results` array. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2906531-max

```
private func showResults(_ results: [(label: String, confidence: Float)]?) {
    if let results = results {
        let biggest = results.max { $0.confidence < $1.confidence }
        if let biggest = biggest {
            let (label, confidence) = biggest
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```